# How exactly is someone conceived by midichlorians

Tags: star-wars

So in Episode 2 we are shown or led to believe that Anankin Skywalker is conceived by midichlorians.

And with the book [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Darth_Plagueis) and questions like these [If Plagueis Caused Anakin's Birth, Why Shmi Skywalker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10654/if-plagueis-caused-anakins-birth-why-shmi-skywalker) and [Did Darth Sidious cause Anakin's virgin birth? [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/did-darth-sidious-cause-anakins-virgin-birth?rq=1) and [Who is Anakin Skywalker's father?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/who-is-anakin-skywalkers-father)

> Skywalker's mother, Shmi Skywalker, claimed that her son was conceived
>   without a father, but could not explain how that had happened. It was
>   the theory of Jedi Master Qui-Gon Jinn that the will of the Force
>   caused his birth. There is evidence to suggest that Skywalker's birth
>   may have been engineered by the Sith Lord Darth Plagueis as part of an
>   experiment in immortality.

### So what is canon for how he was actually conceived?

Comment: When one midichlorian loves another one very much...

Comment: First, the midichlorians have to get someone really drunk...

Comment: @JohnSensebe, So it was a combined efforet then? LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It’s not very clear

Anakin’s conception (assuming that he *was* conceived by the midi-chlorians) is not given in much detail. Even Shmi isn’t much help:

> “There is no father,” she said finally. She shook her head slowly. “I
> carried him, I gave birth to him. I raised him. I can’t tell you any
> more than that.”
>
> <sub>*The Phantom Menace*</sub>

We do have a bit of a clue (albeit a vague one):

> Qui-Gon nodded. “A boy. His cells have the highest concentration of
> midi-chlorians I have ever seen in a lifeform.” He paused. “It is
> possible he was conceived by midi-chlorians.”
>
> There was a shocked silence this time. Qui-Gon Jinn was suggesting the
> impossible, that the boy was conceived **not by human contact, but by
> the essence of all life**, by the connectors to the Force itself, the
> midi-chlorians. Comprising collective consciousness and intelligence,
> the midi-chlorians formed the link between everything living and the
> Force.
>
> <sub>*The Phantom Menace*</sub>

There seems to be the implication that since the midi-chlorians are “the essence of all life,” they’re quite capable of creating it if they so choose.

Some other questions have touched on seeming [biological difficulties](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/shouldnt-anakin-have-been-a-female?rq=1) created by Anakin’s virgin birth. However, what it basically comes down to, in the end, is that the Force is supernatural, and midi-chlorians are fundamentally tied to the Force. **The Force can create energy from nothing, connect minds at speeds faster than light, and [move objects without any reaction force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83142/51379). Why not create a few cells?**

Comment: @KyloRen - It’s nothing to be afraid of, though. *Star Wars* is science fantasy, not hard sci-fi. The Force is *magic*: asking it to obey Newton’s laws is a lot like asking Voldemort to do so.

Comment: asking how Anakin was born without a father is like asking how Jesus was born. Anakin and Jesus were both conceived by magic (ie the Force/the Holy Spirit respectively)